# Using React Redux Loading Bar : Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**EDIT**

Updated and installed the lib with its updated newer package, but now getting the following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
node_modules/react-redux-loading-bar/build/loading_bar.js:300
  297 | 
  298 | var mapStateToProps = function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  299 |   return {
> 300 |     loading: state.loadingBar[ownProps.scope || _loading_bar_ducks.DEFAULT_SCOPE]
  301 |   };
  302 | };
  303 |
```

**PREVIOUS:**

I am using `React Redux Loading Bar` from [TylerMcginnis](https://twitter.com/tylermcginnis) [here](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/react-redux-loading-bar). Please note that I am not using loading bar middleware but instead a dispatch. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
TypeError: state.loadingBar is undefined
Uncaught TypeError: state.loadingBar is undefined
    Redux 7
    React 3
    ConnectFunction Redux
    React 18
    js index.js:20
    Webpack 7
```

Here is the code,

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//    import LoadingBar from 'react-redux-loading';
import LoadingBar from 'react-redux-loading-bar';

function Login({ users, userKeys, loading }) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <LoadingBar />
            <div className='container'>
                {loading ? null : (
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='users'>Please select a User</label>
                        <br />
                        <select id='users' name='usersList'>
                            {userKeys.map(id => (
                                <option value={id}>{users[id].name}</option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </Fragment>

    );
}

function mapStateToProps({ users }) {
    return {
        loading: users === null,
        users,
        userKeys: Object.keys(users)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Reducers index:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { loadingBarReducer } from 'react-redux-loading-bar';
import questions from './questions';
import users from './users';

export default combineReducers({
    loadingBarReducer,
    questions,
    users
});
```

action :

```
export function handleInitialData() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(showLoading());
        return getInitialData().then(({users, questions}) => {
            dispatch(receiveQuestions(questions));
            dispatch(receiveUsers(users));
            dispatch(hideLoading());
        });       
    };
}
```

Comment: you are importing  `LoadingBar` component from wrong module. Change `'react-redux-loading'` => `'react-redux-loading-bar'`

Comment: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux-loading-bar' in ...` ... Changed the lib installed it as well. However now the new error is somewhat similara.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
node_modules/react-redux-loading-bar/build/loading_bar.js:300
  297 | 
  298 | var mapStateToProps = function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  299 |   return {
> 300 |     loading: state.loadingBar[ownProps.scope || _loading_bar_ducks.DEFAULT_SCOPE]
  301 |   };
  302 | };
  303 | 
`

Comment: Ill update that as an edit to my question

Comment: looking through docs you have linked. 
1. `import LoadingBar from 'react-redux-loading-bar'`
2. `<LoadingBar scope="sectionBar" />` (scope  props optional)
3. `import { loadingBarReducer } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'`

Comment: You need to use `react-redux-loading-bar` in reducer too

Comment: let me update the reducer...
however https://github.com/tylermcginnis/react-redux-loading-bar#usage check the first example

Comment: Updated both action and reducer. Did not work. Same error

Comment: I am not sure and I could be wrong but are you sure connect() even works with a functional component ? I didn't use connect() in my functional component but instead used the new hooks (useDispatch, useSelector).

Comment: @HarshaLimaye `connect` works with functional component

Comment: @Ahmed  yes `scope` props is optional

Comment: It does. Just to check however if the problem of this is being with functional component, on my machine I converted my example to a class and it did not work with that either. definitely something else is wrong. Just cant put my finger on it

Comment: may be you can share  your code through codesandbox link

Comment: Here is the link to sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-ritchie-ujgdf?file=/src/reducers/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue while creating a sandbox example for you all :D...

Main Issue:

reducer should have object/field name as `loadingBar` for the library to be able to recognize the reducer.

This one little change fixed the issue in reducer,

```
export default combineReducers({ users, loadingBar: loadingBarReducer });
```

[Here is sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-ritchie-ujgdf?file=/src/reducers/index.js)